# Manually pass multiple integer values to a SSRS sureport

Tags: t-sql, reporting-services, subreport

I'm trying to pass multiple integer values to a subreport, in order to use the following SQL request :

```
SELECT *
FROM Table as T
WHERE Code IN (@Code)
```

I want to pass 3 integer values to @Code: 1,2 and 3

I tried to use various combination of Split() and Join(), but none worked.

Comment: The values you are trying to pass are selected from a parameter of the main report?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to do anything. If your parameter is set to be multi-value and takes it's values from a query or list of integers then SSRS will automatically inject a comma separated list of values into your main dataset query.

In your case if values 1, 2 & 3 were selected and you main dataset looked like your example

```
SELECT *
FROM Table as T
WHERE Code IN (@Code)
```

then what actually gets passed to the server would be this..

```
SELECT *
FROM Table as T
WHERE Code IN (1,2,3)
```

There is no need to do JOINS or SPLITS and no need to change dataset parameters. It will just work.

Answer (score 0):

When I use a multi-value parameter in SSRS I have to use a table-valued function in the query. Essentially, it turns your parameter into a table that you can INNER JOIN on. For example:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table as T
INNER JOIN tablevaluefuntion(@Code,',') as P--the ',' is the delimiter from your list
WHERE t.code = p.value
```